# recursion error with pyinstaller

Tags: python, macos, recursion, python-3.6, pyinstaller

I'm trying using pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py
```

to create a standalone python app, but keep getting a recursion limit error:

```
for field, value in iter_fields(node):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

This is a rather common problem online (a few SO questions, google groups, open github issue), but none of the proposed solutions seem to work.

I've tried increasing the recursion limit in the `driver.spec` file, downgrading to python 3.5... nothing seems to work.  Is there a way to get this to work?  More broadly, how can I create an executable that is cross-platform?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to launch pyinstaller in this way?

From **cmd**:

c:/pyinstallerfolder/pyinstaller.py c:/yourscriptfolder/main.py (main is the main file of your application)

Comment: I'm using macos